# intellij Debugger is not able to connect with Remote VM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jnlp

I am working on a JNLP based application which is hosted on JBOSS server. My IDE is intellij . When I tried to do the remote debug on the port defined for that the on Debug console of intellij this message is written

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'camelot-dev.kwcorp.com:8787',
    transport: 'socket'
```

from this message, I thought that I am connected with the Remote VM and I jumped into the workspace for debugging but nothing seems to be working for me. When I clicked on F6 and respective buttons for debugging nothing seems to working (no debug happened). I checked the debug port and it is correct. I am not sure that whether I am doing the correct thing or not.

Comment: Did the jboss server expose that port that intellij's debugger is listening to ?